# How to remove session id "/?___SID=U" from home page URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, sessionid

I want to remove session id from the home page URL using .htaccess file.

I have tried it so many time but can't succeeded. I have disabled the option from the back-end in the session validation setting use sid on front-end I have disabled it but it can't work.

Please suggest me, what is the proper way to remove the session id from home page URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _SID= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [L,R=302]
```